# Override django include template tag to read the html from database

Tags: python, html, templates, django-1.9

I'm trying to write my own custom Django [include template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include), to read the text to render from database, instead of reading a HTML file from disk. Something like this:

```
{% dbinclude 'template_id_from_database' with foo='bar' %}
```

A query would be raised to get some HTML text containing variables from database, and those variables would be replaced with their values, passed vía *with* keyword.

That would be my approach, but reading the documentation, looks like there may be an easier way. Related with the variable passed to *include* tag, it says that:

> The variable may also be any object with a render() method that
>   accepts a context. This allows you to reference a compiled Template in
>   your context.

So, instead of writing my own include template tag, I could just pass an instance of a Template object (or a subclass) as argument. In that instance, I could read the text to render from database. Still don't know how to do that, but the concept is here.

So, the question is: **what of these approaches would be more *Django-good-practices-friendly*, if any?**